# Differences between OkHttp Mock Web Server and Retrofit Mock

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

OkHttp offers a MockWebServer as a separate library called "mockwebserver".

Similarly, Retrofit provides a library named "retrofit-mock".

What is the difference between those two libraries? Which one should we use for doing instrumentation testing on Android?

Answer (score 2):

According to [JakeWharton](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2340)

> MockRetrofit is about stubbing your API before it gets to the HTTP client. If you want the full HTTP stack you should use something like MockWebServer in OkHttp to simulate a server and allow customizing the requests and responses to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't much information on Retrofit Mock but I managed to find some.

I think Retrofit Mock is easier to use, at least you do not have to start and wait for the base url from MockWebServer and pass it to retrofit. It is more straight forward.

sample:

https://riggaroo.co.za/retrofit-2-mocking-http-responses/

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-mock/src/test/java/retrofit2/mock/BehaviorDelegateTest.java

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleMockService.java

The package:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock/src/main/java/retrofit2/mock

CREDIT: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1413